# Is it safe to compare boost::typeindex type hash_code() across different platforms over network?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, hash, typeid

Is it safe to say, compute a type hash using boost typeindex hash_code in machine A, then send this hash to machine B over the network, and then, in the machine B, use this hash to discover the type the machine A was "talking about".

Boils down to, is the result of boost::typeindex::hash_code cross platform?
Can I compute this hash in, say a Playstation 4, and then check this hash in a PC running Linux and in another PC running Windows and in an XBox?

I've been looking for this answer for a long time now, and I'm not 100% sure this is guaranteed. If this is not guaranteed, how would I be able to implement such thing?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that you can rely on it. But I cannot really prove it.

Comment: Of course not. Why would it be. Hashing functions are usually implementation defined, not to mention the typeids themselves which - blatantly obviously - are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is the result of boost::typeindex::hash_code cross platform?

Absolutely not.

`hash_code` is not even required to produce the same value for two consecutive builds of the program. It should never be stored or communicated anywhere outside a running program.

> how would I be able to implement such thing?

You'd want a deterministic hash of a deterministic "type name". You would need to provide your own protocol for producing the "type name" (a static method which produces a string, for example) and then you would need to hash that that name with a well known algorithm (SHA1, for example).

#### Before anyone argues...

Any counter-arguments, no matter how carefully phrased are wrong. boost::hash is based on the library extensions technical report n1836 (which you can find [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1836.pdf))

Section 6.3.3 (2) says:

> The return value of operator() is **unspecified**, except that equal arguments yield the same result. operator() shall not throw exceptions

Comment: I don't think the second part of the answer (about portable hash functions) is relevant, because there is no portable type identification in the first place. There is no way in C++ (or Boost.TypeIndex) to produce a portable string or other identifier from a type. You'd have to either decode the string produced by your compiler's `typeid(T).name()` and construct some portable name from it or use an ad-hoc solution such as defining a nested user-defined string (`const char T::name[]`) and using that as the type id. Only then you can apply a portable hash to that portable string.